# Why does ThreadPoolExecutor use a HashSet to maintain a reference to its worker threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, hashset, threadpoolexecutor

The `ThreadPoolExecutor` class maintains this `Set` of `Worker` references:

```
/**
 * Set containing all worker threads in pool. Accessed only when
 * holding mainLock.
 */
private final HashSet<Worker> workers = new HashSet<>();
```

Why does it use a `HashSet` to do so?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that in the context of `ThreadPoolExecutor` the order of iteration on the set of workers is not important **and** `add` and `remove` operation in `HashSet` are constant time.